# On showing a distribution is a function

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Consider the distributional equation
$$\Delta \omega-\omega=\mu$$
Then it is easy to verify by Fourier transform that
$$\omega=-\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{|\cdot|^2+1}\hat{\mu}\right)$$
is the only solution of the above equation. Now let $\mu\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be defined by
$$\mu(\varphi)=\int_\mathbb{R}\varphi(0,y)\ dt,\forall \varphi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R^2})$$
The problem asks to show that $\omega$ is a bounded function on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Intuitively we can calculate as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\omega(\varphi)&=(-\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{|\cdot|^2+1}\hat{\mu}\right),\varphi)\\
&=(\hat{\mu},-\frac{1}{|\cdot|^2+1}\mathcal{F}^{-1}\varphi)\\
&={-1 \over {2\pi}}(\mu,f*\varphi)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where $f=\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{|\cdot|^2+1}\right) \in L^2$ since $\frac{1}{|\cdot|^2+1} \in L^2$. Now we compute formally with
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\omega(\varphi)&={-1 \over {2\pi}}(\mu,f*\varphi)\\
&={-1 \over {2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}_y}f*\varphi(0,y)\ dy\\
&={-1 \over {2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}_y}\ dy\int_{\mathbb{R}^2_\eta}f(x-\eta)\varphi(\eta)|_{x=(0,y)}\ d\eta\\
&={-1 \over {2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2_\eta} \varphi(\eta)\ d\eta\int_{\mathbb{R}_y}f(-\eta_1,y)\ dy
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Now formally define
$$\omega(x,y)={-1 \over {2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(-x,z)\ dz$$
and I want to do estimation to it but have no idea of how to proceed. Am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The Schwartz class is preserved under multiplication by $\frac{1}{|x|^2+1}$, hence convolution with $f$ is also a closed operation. $f$ might not be a function but its convolution with $\varphi$ is. Now, by a simple Fubini + Plancherel argument it is easy to compute the action of $\mu$ on that convolution.

Comment: @Guillermo I am sorry but I don't quite get your idea..How can I apply Fubini or Plancherel argument to some non-function?

Comment: You are right, there are some details left. I'll write a full answer.

Comment: What happens when you expand f out in your last expression with Fourier transform and try another Fubini? Also isn't f a function in L2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are only left with showing that $\omega$ is bounded. Writing out the Fourier transform:
$$
\omega(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{+2\pi i 0 z}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-2\pi i z \xi_2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{+2\pi i x \xi_1} \frac{1}{1+\xi_1^2+\xi_2^2} d\xi_1 \, d\xi_2 \, dz.
$$

By Fourier inversion we can cancel the two outer integrals substituting $\xi_2 = 0$, so we arrive at
$$
\omega(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{+2\pi i x \xi_1} \frac{1}{1+\xi_1^2} \, d\xi_1.
$$
And this is bounded since $1/(1+x^2)$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's so ashamed that I did not realize it is a simple result of the inversion formula...I just took the absolute sign into the integral and find it diverges..Thank you!